# Самоучитель assembler

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте.
Не могли ли Вы подсказать неплохой самоучитель по ассемблеру? Желательно, чтобы в конце каждой главы были упражнения, а также были куски кода с комментариями (например, hello world).

P.S. На хеше похожего вопроса не нашел, а точнее ответа на него.

Comment: > похожего вопроса не нашел

[поссибле дупликате](http://hashcode.ru/questions/77802)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Учил ассемблер по книге "**Магда - Ассемблер для процессоров Intel Pentium**" . Магда как автор очень понятно и доходчиво объясняет даже тяжелый материал.
Также неплохие учебники:

- Голубь - Искусство программирования
     на Ассемблере. Лекции и упражнения
- Зубков - Assembler для DOS, Windows и
     UNIX
- Кулаков - Программирование на аппаратном уровне
- Ирвин - Язык ассемблера для процессоров Intel
- Марек - Ассемблер на примерах. Базовый курс
- Пирогов - Assembler. Учебный курс
- Assembler&Win32. Курс молодого бойца

Comment: Вопрос немного не по теме, но у меня процессор от AMD, подойдет ли мне "Магда - Ассемблер для процессоров Intel Pentium"?

Comment: подойдёт. Процессоры AMD поддерживают 32 битные и 16 битные х86 инструкции, что позволяет использовать любое программное обеспечение без необходимости перекомпиляции . Также наборы команд MMX и SSE тоже будут поддерживаться

Answer (score 3):

В свое время начинал изучение АСМа с советской брошюры (названия и автора, к сожалению, не помню) и подаренного учебника Юрова. Что-то типа этого: Виктор Юров "Assembler. Учебник для вузов". Но советская брошюра помогла понять идею ассемблера.

Comment: Идея ассемблера -- замена цифровых кодов операций на символьные и введение меток (с расчётом разных адресных извратов в зависимости от архитектуры) вместо ручного распределения адресов и вычисления смещений, а также программная сборка модулей (отсюда и название). Плюс прибамбасы. В макроассемблере ещё макропроцессор.

Comment: Речь идет о понимании основ программирования на АСМе. К тому времени имелся опыт программирования на ЯВУ, но вот АСМ представлялся чем-то совершенно "диким". А брошюрка разложила все по полкам. Начать изучение АСМа пытался с того же учебника Юрова, но он оказался полезен при наличии базовых знаний.

Comment: В принципе интересно, что же дикого в ассемблере по сравнению, скажем, с C? Переходы самому расписывать (когда на `C` `goto` писал, уже и не помню) или низкоуровневые трюки? Или имеются в виду  особенности архитектуры x86?

Comment: Без базы по архитектуре машин ассемблер по настоящему не освоить. Надо изучить парочку (желательно не очень похожих), потом пойдет, как по маслу.
А если смотреть "вообще", то есть замечательная книга Д. Кнута.

Answer (score 0):

Вот очень хороший учебник [Пирогов В. Ассемблер для Windows](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785977500845&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0).

Comment: Я с АСМом почти незнаком, видимо книги автор считает, что читатель обладает начальными знаниями, увы мне это не подходит ... Мне нужен самоучитель "с нуля". Есть ли такой на примете?

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, это мое мнение, но что-бы учить хлл нужно освоить низкоуровневое программирование. Мне очень понравился учебник Зубков С. - Assembler для DOS, Windows, UNIX. Примеры на `TASM`, конечно, но для понимания очень годится. А если нравится другой компилятор, можно перепилить голову и конец программы, на начальной стадии обучения код везде одинаковый.

Answer (score 0):

Про Калашникова забыли, а зря. Хорошая книга [**«Ассемблер — это просто. Учимся программировать»**](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785977505918&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0).